# Get perticular records based on the hour and the driverID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm creating a mongo database which stores array of objects of the following form

`{ 
    _id: 5ca37dc35b55092ab2b0980e,
    driverID: 'cjttwclbr00ui0714y2dodxe2',
    createdAt: 2019-04-02T15:20:35.021Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-04-02T15:20:35.021Z, __v: 0 
}`

I want to filter those results which belongs to a particular driver based on the day and hour

eg: I want to get all the records which created on 2nd hour of today which belongs to a particular driver

How can I write find query or aggregation method based on this scenario?

I can get hour of the day using

```
const hour = new Date().getHours();
```

Comment: can you please share the full schema of the collection.?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the driver data b/w a particular hour

```
    var date = new Date(); // for today
    date.setHours(n,0,0,0); // n is the hour

    var endHour = new Date();
    endHour.setHours(n+1,0,0,0);

    var query = {
    driverID:driverId,
    createdAt :{ $gte:date,$lt:endHour}
    }

    db.collection.find(query);
```